# Mandatory Fields For WooCommerce Products Before Publishing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a B2B WordPress (WooCommerce) website where vendors are salespeople are able to upload their own products to their accounts. I am looking at making a couple of the fields "mandatory" before the user can submit the product into live view. I found a couple of solutions that people have done for like weight and length in the shipping section, and those worked great, however, I have a couple of drop downs that are part of a different plugin/theme that I want to be required, as well as the "Product Category" to have a specific option selected outside of the 'Uncategorized' option. Does anyone know of a current solution to this, or how to achieve this?